# Linux Mint blank desktop environment

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, desktop-environment, display-settings

I am running Linux Mint 18.3 with the Cinnamon desktop.

I just ran a steam update.

Afterwards my Cinnamon desktop is gone. The only thing showing is the wallpaper.

I can open up applications that have keyboard shortcuts like chrome, file manager, and the terminal, but every aspect of the desktop environment is gone.

So far I have tried rebooting and restarting Cinnamon. Should my next step be to uninstall steam? Is there a way I can roll back the steam update?

What log file should I be looking in for relevant error lines?

Comment: Fill a [bugreport](https://linuxmint-troubleshooting-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)